# Ubuntu Machine Reboots instead of Switching to a Virtual Console

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I just discovered this today and haven't been able to find any info elsewhere.  On one of our labs running Ubuntu 8.04, I tried to switch to a virtual console (Ctrl-Alt-F[1-6]). Instead of switching to the console, though, the machine reboots.

I don't even know where to start trying to fix this, any ideas?

I ran all the updates and messed with the restricted drivers we were using and got nowhere.  We're about to roll out 9.04 on our machines and hope that fixes it; if not, I'll be back here, I'm sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Are you using X11 when this happens or are you switching between text consoles? Is your kernel tainted i.e. do you have any binary drivers installed?)

First, **install all Ubuntu 8.04 updates** (esp for the kernel) and test if the problem disappears. Probably you're not the first who runs into this (esp with this old distribution) and maybe there is already a fix available.

If the problem persists decide between trying the **upgrade to Ubuntu 9.04** (the easy way) **or** trying to find the culprit of the problem (a little bit harder) by **capturing a kernel panic**: Connect your machine with a serial cable to a second machine (see `Documentation/serial-console.txt` in the kernel sources for an explanation). Alternatively you can try to capture the panic with `netconsole` (which sends the kernel panic as a UDP packet to a 2nd machine). Google "netconsole" and you'll find explanations how to do this.

Now, if you manage to capture the panic post the **entire** panic message here and chances are not bad that we'll be able to determine the culprit (you could e.g. search at [kerneloops](http://kerneloops.org/) for the function name that appear at the top of the call trace or at the instruction pointer (EIP) address).

Comment: Go for upgradation / update of packages if kernel panic debugging looks scary.

Answer (score 1):

This can have many causes. One of the things to check would be if the file

```
/etc/default/console-setup
```

has a line

```
ACTIVE_CONSOLES="/dev/tty[1-6]"
```

in it.

Also check in /etc/events.d that the ttys are configured correctly and not all set in the same way as the control-alt-delete file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if you are out of diskspace (or memory for that matter).  I have had logon problems when the root partition fills up.

Answer (score 0):

txwikinger is right. If the pc works correctly I suppose someone (with root access) made a trick manipulating the configuration files for ctrl+alt+f1 :-)

above all check the file /etc/event.d/control-alt-delete and check this [post](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-disable-ctrl-alt-del-keys/#comments)